A question on Shelstad's $L$-packets description
In her article "L-indistinguishability for real groups", Shelstad gives a description of the $L$-packets attached to a real Langlands parameter of a reductive group $G$.
This is theorem 4.3.2 of the article.
The description is as follows. Let $\phi$ be a Langlands parameter of $G(\mathbb{R})$. Let $W_{\mathbb{R}}$ be the real Weyl group attached to $G$ (and a choice of maximal torus). Then, for each $w\in W_{\mathbb{R}}$, we can construct non-zero distributions
$$\Theta(\phi,w):\mathcal{C}_{c}^{\infty}(G(\mathbb{R}))\rightarrow\mathbb{C}.$$
In the case where $\phi$ is attached to a discrete series representation whose infinitesimal character is regular then we claim (beginning of p.406) that we can attach a discrete series representation of $G(\mathbb{R} )$ denoted $\pi(\phi,w)$, having global character $\Theta(\phi,w)$.
Question Can anyone give one or more references where the construction of the discrete series $\pi(\phi,w)$ having global character $\Theta(\phi,w)$ is given?

There are many. Here are three that come to mind. Other people can add their favorites.

Representation Theory of Semisimple Groups: An Overview Based on Examples, Chapter IX Tony Knapp (excellent introduction)

Contragredient Representations and Characterizing the local Langlands Correspondence, Jeffrey Adams and David Vogan (perhaps the most efficient treatment).

Discrete Series L-packets for real reductive groups, Jeffrey Adams and Tasho Kaletha (all the details worked out in the most general setting).



Hi, thank you for the references. Unfortunately, I'm not able to find what I was looking for in your references. Can you tell where it is done? Moreover, chapter X of Knapp's book is building global character so I don't really see how there could be the construction I'm looking for in the previous chapter... (Please note that I'm not expert)

Chapter IX of Knapp gives a construction (due to Flensted-Jensen). See the Notes to Chapter IX at the end of the book. Another approach is Atiyah-Schmid, A Geometric Construction of Discrete Series for Semisimple Lie Groups, Inventiones 1977. No construction is easy. Harish-Chandra classified the DS in terms of their global characters so Chapter IX + X of Knapp (or using the other references) gives a connection from $\phi$ to the character to the discrete series.

ok thank you :)
